# Can I subscribe to non-http data and how?

Tags: angular, observable

I am building a shopping cart and I would like to have my shopping cart icon display the number of items in the cart.

For the moment I do not have an API set up for the shopping cart yet as it is not a priority. So, for now, i just have a service that has an array of items where one gets added every time I click on "Add to Cart".

My problem is that when I add things to the shopping cart, the icon and count in the menu bar are not updated.

How can I achieve this without resorting to a http service?

**Mock Cart Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ShoppingcartService {
    //MOCK SERVICE

//fields
items: any[] = [];



//constructor
constructor() { }

//public methods

addToShoppingcart(item: any) {
     this.items.push(item);
}

removeFromShoppingcart() {

}

changeQuantity() {

}

getAllItems() {
    return this.items;
}

getItemsCount() {
    return this.items.length;

}
```

**Shopping Cart Icon TS**

```
export class ShoppingcartIconComponent implements OnInit {
count: number;


constructor(private shoppingcartService: ShoppingcartService) {
    this.count = this.shoppingcartService.getItemsCount();
}

ngOnInit() {

}
```

}

**Shopping Cart Icon Html**

```
    <div class="btn btn-outline-info cart">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">

  </i>
  <div class="count">
    {{count}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The component where the Add to Cart is..

**HTML**

```
  <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="addToCart()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> {{shoppingCartTitle}}
  </button>
```

**TS**

```
   export class AlbumdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    shoppingcart;

    album: any[];
    id: number;

    shoppingCartTitle: string = "Add to shoppingcart";

    constructor(private musicService: MusicService,
           private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private shoppingcartService: ShoppingcartService) 
       {
            this.shoppingcart = this.shoppingcartService.getAllItems();
        }
    ngOnInit() {
//

    }

}

    addToCart() {
        this.shoppingcartService.addToShoppingcart(this.album);
    }

}
```

Quick screenshot of the situation, the Json shows that there is indeed an item in the cart, but the counter stays at 0.
The components are not parent or child of eachother, one is in the menu, the other is in the main view.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just return an observable of those items, using `Observable.of()`

Here are couple of methods you can modify:

```
addToShoppingcart(item: any) {
     this.items.push(item);
     return Observable.of({message:'Item Added', addedItem: item})
     //note that object can be anything you want to mock
}


removeFromShoppingcart() {
  return Observable.of({message:'Item Deleted'});
}

changeQuantity() {
}

getAllItems() {
    return Observable.of(this.items); //this automatically wraps the array in an observable
}

getItemsCount() {
    return Observable.of(this.items.length); //this returns a number, but is wrapped in an observable

}
```

And the rest of the code you can treat each of them as observable as you would normally do, i.e subscribe to them. For example, in your constructor, you can do this:

```
constructor(private shoppingcartService: ShoppingcartService) {
    this.shoppingcartService.getItemsCount()
        .subscribe(count=>this.count = count);
}
```

Note: to use `Observable.of`, remember to import it:

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
```

## Edit:

I am keeping the above service codes for reference because they answers the question title.

If you want to have your `items[]` being updated asynchronously every time you call `addToShoppingCart()`, you will need to create a `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` to keep track of it. In the example below we will use `BehaviourSubject` because it allows intialization of a default value.

In your service, make a property called `itemBSubject` with type of `BehaviourSubject`. Do not confuse this with `items[]`. This subject is to keep track of your `items[]`.

```
items: any[] = [];
itemBSubject: BehaviourSubject<any[]>
```

In your constructor, sync up `itemBSubject` with `items`:

```
constructor() {
   this.itemBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(items); 
}
```

Now, in **every** method that modifies the `items[]`, you will need to update the `itemBSubject` as well, by using the `.next()`:

```
addToShoppingcart(item: any) {
     this.items.push(item);
     this.itemBSubject.next(this.items); // this will update the behavior subject
     return this.itemBSubject.asObservables();

}

//same goes to delete. call .next() after this items are sliced.
```

And now here is the magic of all. For your `getItems()` and also `getItemsCount()`, return the `BehaviourSubject` (as an observable).

```
getItems(){
    return this.itemBSubject.asObservable()
}

getItemsCount(){
   return this.itemBSubject.asObservable()
    .map(items=>items.length)
}
```

And now, you will realize your `count` will automatically being incremented, even though you are adding the item in another component.

Comment: This is the simplicity i was hoping for, but it is still not working unfortunately

Comment: @Vahx ah, what is the roadblock?

Comment: Same as before unfortunately, the counter stays at 0. Added some console.log() which shows me that the getItemsCount() method is never called when added things to the cart

Comment: Update: The observable does work when i call `GetAllItems()` and then do `{{items.length}}`  in the HTML. But the getItemsCount does not work as expected. Either way, thank you so far for you help. I will see if i can figure out how to load just the count instead of the whole cart. :)

Comment: @Vahx see edit. If you are still confused, we need to go to chat

Comment: Getting a Circular Reference error to Json when subscribing to the count.But I'll find a way to work around this Thankx for your effort and assistance, I would upvote again for the edit if I could.

2 small things: `this.itemBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(items); ` I think this should be `this.items` right? and you have `Behaviour` spelled sometimes with an `u`

Comment: Found the Circular Reference: `getItems(){
    return this.itemBSubject.asObservable()
}` Because this is also an observable but my ts is not set up to receive an observable... so when i just `return this.items` it works like it should, again thank you very much for your time and effort for this simple explanation